# How to convert a datetime with time zone to the UTC time in python

Tags: python, datetime, utc, python-dateutil

I've used `dateutil` to convert the string `'Wed, 19 Dec 2012 01:34:52 -0800'` to date time `datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 19, 1, 34, 52, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -28800))`.
How can I convert it to UTD+0 `datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 19, 9, 34, 52)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.astimezone()` method:

```
dt.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
```

Comment: @ShawnChin, you can also use the `dateutil` UTC implementation `tzutc()`.

Comment: @ShawnChin: You can use any module that has a UTC representation. `dateutil` has one for you, as does [`iso8601`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601/).